# Seek app to find dupes based on jpg metadata

Tags: images, libraries, metadata, jpeg, duplicate

I'm dealing with a decade's worth of digital photos where I want to be sure i have one and only one of every .jpg is stored in my new master picture repository.

I'm aggregating lots of backup CDs as archival hard drives - this means i can't trust the file date when checking for dupes.

I need something that's able to look into the metadata within the jpg itself.

thx

Comment: I wrote a python script to find and delete duplicate files once, it generated checksums to find a duplicate, and was pretty fast. Have you considered just a normal duplicate checker? If not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to look at the metadata either.  What you want is a tool to match pictures by similarity, in case there's been any minor editing, tagging, or recompression done to them.

Some programs I know of off the top of my head, but haven't extensively tested, are [DupliFinder](http://duplifinder.codeplex.com/), [imgSeek](http://www.imgseek.net/), and [VisiPics](http://www.visipics.info/).

DownloadSquad showcased DupliFinder a while back, and the discussion turned up some other alternatives.  [DownloadSquad Post](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2008/05/21/duplifinder-find-duplicate-and-similar-images-on-your-pc/).  (Oh hey, I participated in that too.  Go figure.)